# xamarin forms syncfusion ListView ItemAppearing

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, syncfusion, xamarin.forms-styles

I use syncfusion listview to create listview on xamarin forms

I want to use the ItemAppearing option in listview

I used this EXAMPLE on website:https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/cref_files/xamarin/Syncfusion.SfListView.XForms~Syncfusion.ListView.XForms.SfListView.html

and this EXAMPLE: https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/cref_files/xamarin/Syncfusion.SfListView.XForms~Syncfusion.ListView.XForms.SfListView~ItemAppearing_EV.html#ExampleBookmark

I use this example and found this problem

```
ListView.ItemAppearing +=listView_ItemAppearing;

public void listView_ItemAppearing(object sender, Syncfusion.ListView.XForms.ItemAppearingEventArgs e)
        {
           var temp= e.ItemData as IEnumerable<ListViewCall>;
            //temp.ToList();
        }
```

I cast `e.ItemData` to `List<ListViewCall>`  and get `null`

`e.ItemData` has data but `var temp` is `null`

Why would this be?

Comment: e.ItemData is not an IEnumerable.  It is just single value from your List, not all values

Comment: This is a good example of the difference between direct casting and casting with `as` keyword. With `(IEnumerable<ListViewCall>)e.ItemData;` you would've received a runtime exception and had a better clue of what's wrong but with `as` you just get a null if the cast is invalid, no exception.

Comment: Thank you for response but this cast is invalid!

Answer (score 0):

**ItemData** ：Gets the underlying data object of the ListViewItem when item appearing from the bound data source.

so `e.ItemData` will return you the binding object. like the example above,it will return the object `BookInfo`.

```
public void listView_ItemAppearing(object sender, Syncfusion.ListView.XForms.ItemAppearingEventArgs e)
    {
       var temp= e.ItemData as BookInfo;           
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
           public void listView_ItemAppearing(object sender, Syncfusion.ListView.XForms.ItemAppearingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ItemData is GroupResult)
        {
            var listViewCalls = (e.ItemData as GroupResult).Items as EnumerableQuery<ListViewCall>;
            foreach (var listViewCall in listViewCalls)
            {

            }
        }
        else if (e.ItemData is ListViewCall)
        {
            var listViewCall = e.ItemData as ListViewCall;


        }


        // foreach (Object obj in e.ItemData.GetType().GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
        // {
        //    string s = (obj as Call).Title;
        //}


    }
```